# tinyMCE/PHP: How to retrieve and reinsert BLOB data into the textarea to allow re-editing

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce, blob

PHP/mySQL:  Configured tinyMCE with base64 image upload feature.

Can save entire textarea (text & image) to mySQL as a BLOB.
Can retrieve blob and echo to web page.  Page renders correctly as was arranged in tinyMCE editor.

However, I would like to allow the user to edit the same content within tinyMCE again -> retrieve the BLOB and display it within tinyMCE textarea so it appears exactly how it was, allowing the user to edit as before in tinyMCE.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what have you tried/done so far?

Comment: @Thariama - see below my answer.  Works, but seems slow...

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple approach which does what I wanted.  First, retrieve the blob from MySQL into a PHP variable, say $blob.  Then place this into the form/textbox as shown below, and when the page is loaded, you get the tinyMCE form ready to edit exactly what you had before:

```
<form method="post" action="submittest.php">
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"><?= $blob ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

However, I do notice a bit of a delay for the form to load with text and images...not sure why (would appreciate if someone can give insight to this - maybe the base64 takes more time to process?).  Alternately, storing the images on the local machine as jpg's and loading the form with image references was instantaneous.  As simple as the other method is, I think I'll default to remote image referencing (because of speed) rather than the base64 in a blob as originally intended.

Comment: i think the delay is caused by the base64 images